# Gmail not receiving my mails anymore after accidental massive send (10k+)

Tags: gmail

I messed up something on my code and made my server send **10k+ emails** to my own email address last night.

After receiving ~8k this morning, I barely haven't received any mail in the last 8 hours besides *sometimes* one of the automated ones at a rate of ~10/hour.

Has anyone already experienced this?

I haven't found how to tell gmail about this. Nowhere I have a message saying "your mailbox is slowed down because of abusing use" or something.

Can anyone help or should I wait and go on vacation for a few days?

---

Edit:

Thanks for the help. To add more details:

Those emails have been sent from a non-gmail SMTP server, say `example.com` to `me@example.com`, which I automatically redirect to `myaddress@gmail.com`.

I thought at first that the problem was coming from the `example.com` mail server, but it happens this parts works very well for sending **and** receiving for any other `email@example.com`.

My emails sent from `myaddress@gmail.com` are also sent. It is only to receive a mail in `myaddress@gmail.com` inbox that it won't work.

This makes me guess that this is not a SPAM-filtering issue, since sending works fine.

---

Edit2:

@bearacuda13, there ain't much code to show. The sequence of failures are:

1. A [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) that calls itself recursively every hour, silently increasing the number of jobs in the database, without any error
2. A heroku API sunset that starts to make them fail all at once.
3. An exception mailer to tell me about the exception raised

Done :)

Comment: I've heard of minutely stuff being accidentally used instead of hourly/daily/whatever. If you could post the code that's screwing up, you'd have much, much, better odds of any of us having a clue what's happening.

Comment: I edited my question but there ain't much code to show unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution has been to wait. In 24 hours I still had not received them all, but at got some message:

[image: Delivery incomplete gmail]

which made me feel like messages were on their way.

48 hours later, I now have the feeling I caught up with all my emails.

If this occurs to you, be patient!

Answer (score 2):

Try https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to see if you've been added to a blacklist.  If you have, it's a serious pain to get off of those lists.

When you send mail, it gets routed through several areas on the internet before winding up in your gmail.  Any of those routes has the possibility to flag and blacklist emails from someone they think is a spammer.  If you're sending 10k emails in an hour, you've probably triggered the "spammer" criteria.

To get off the lists, you need to contact the organization that has blacklisted you.  It might be easier to get a new static IP or domain name.

Comment: Thanks. I checked your tool and everything's fine there. Besides, sending email works well, I only have issues receiving them... I edited my question with more details.